# py-applescript issues with mail?

Tags: python, email, applescript

I am trying to call apple scripts from within python. I have been using `py-applescript`. I'm trying to fetch my mail from the Mail app and dump contents into a directory. (This mail account has only 50 odd emails.) The following script works great when run from the "Script Editor" but goes into the "on error" branch when executed inside python.

```
import applescript 

fetch_mail_test_scpt = applescript.AppleScript('''
    tell application "Mail"
        set destinationFolder to ":Users:ranjit:Workspace:CRA:"
        set my_counter to 0
        repeat with theMessage in (every message of inbox)
            set this_content to source of theMessage
            set my_counter to my_counter + 1
            set coerced_to_string to my_counter as string
            set targetFile to destinationFolder & coerced_to_string
            try
                set my_file to open for access file targetFile with write permission
                set eof of my_file to 0
                write this_content to my_file
                close access my_file
            on error
                try
                    close file targetFile
                    ---return "coming here"
                end try
                ---return "error!!?"
            end try
        end repeat
        return my_counter
    end tell
''')

print(fetch_mail_test_scpt.run())
```

This python script returns the value of the counter. If you uncomment "return "error!!?"" then it returns error. Basically, it's not able to access the file. Is this some kind of known issue with py-applescript? Or is there a workaround? Thanks! 
(In general, py-applescript has been working great for the 4-5 scripts I have written.)

Comment: Out of curiosity: are you aware that Mail messages are stored as human-readable .emlx files in the subfolders of `/Users/ranjit/Library/Mail/…`? While I'm not sure where you're heading with your script, it might be easier to rather use something like `cp` (or python equivalents) instead.

Comment: I would have guessed, but didn't look there. Thanks for the info though. The applescript gives a very clean solution and I want to call it from other python scripts. Also, I believe the applescript can be easily customized to search through email with filters etc., and wouldn't want to do all that heavy-lifting in python, no?

Comment: Apparently it's a known issue in py-applescript...

Comment: "Apparently it's a known issue in py-applescript..." -- [scratches head] I would recommend that you 1. Use an absolute HFS path string as HFS paths are nasty, janky things as it is (or, better, an absolute POSIX path string, since POSIX paths avoid HFS flaws entirely). 2. Add some debug code to the `on error...end` clause to display the error message as that will immediately tell you more about what's actually going wrong and why than any amount of blind guessing.

Comment: OK, you cracked it. "Macintosh HD:Users:..." instead of "Users:..." solves everything. Thanks foo! (Also, I don't know how to add debug code etc... I'm an applescript newbie... Also, I'd appreciate suggestions for good tutorials.)